# mysql query result is not displaying some rows

Tags: mysql

I am confused on how to query the following table. I simply want to show a count of how many was ordered and received on a specific date.

calendar table

```
id  |  date
1   |  2013-07-01 
2   |  2013-07-02 
3   |  2013-07-03 
4   |  2013-07-04 
5   |  2013-07-05
6   |  2013-07-06
7   |  2013-07-07
```

phone_details table

```
id   |  dateOrdered    | dateReceived | upg
1    |  2013-07-01     | 2013-07-05   | exp
2    |  2013-07-02     | 2013-07-05   | post
3    |  2013-07-02     | 2013-07-06   | upgrade
4    |  2013-07-07     | 2013-07-07   | upggrade
5    |  2013-07-03     | 2013-07-04   | exp
6    |  2013-07-01     | 2013-07-02   | exp
```

What I would like the result to be.

```
calendar.date  | noOrdered   |  noReceived  | # of post  | # of exp  | # of upgrade
2013-07-01     | 2           |              |            | 2         |
2013-07-02     | 2           |  1           | 1          |           | 1
2013-07-03     | 1           |              |            | 1         |
2013-07-04     |             |  1           |            |           |
2013-07-05     |             |  2           |            |           |
2013-07-06     |             |  1           |            |           |
2013-07-07     | 1           |  1           |            | 1         |
```

Here is my query:

```
select calendar.date,DAYNAME(calendar.date) as `day`,
sum(if((`phone_details`.`upg` = 'Post'),1,0)) AS `Post Paid`,
sum(if((`phone_details`.`upg` = 'Upgrade'),1,0)) AS `Upgrade`,
sum(if(((`phone_details`.`upg` = 'Exp') or (`phone_details`.`upg` = 'Future Exp')),1,0)) AS `Exp`,
(select count(phone_ID) FROM phone_details 
        WHERE dateReceived = calendar.date 
        )AS `received`

from `phone_details` JOIN calendar
where calendar.date = phone_details.dateOrdered

group by calendar.date DESC
```

The problem with this query is if there is nothing ordered on a date, it does not display it on the result so even if there was a receive on that date it still is not displayed. My result simply looks like the table below instead of the one above. If I subquery each column, I am able to produce the result I want but the processing time seems to slow down considerably.

```
calendar.date  | noOrdered   |  noReceived  | # of post  | # of exp  | # of upgrade
2013-07-01     | 2           |              |            | 2         |
2013-07-02     | 2           |  1           | 1          |           | 1
2013-07-03     | 1           |              |            | 1         |
2013-07-07     | 1           |  1           |            | 1         |
```

Some guidance would be appreciated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want a `LEFT JOIN` to generate results for each row in `calendar` even if they don't match anything in your `phone_details` table;

```
SELECT c.date "calendar_date", 
  SUM(c.date=pd.dateOrdered) noOrdered,
  SUM(c.date=pd.dateReceived) noReceived,
  SUM(c.date=pd.dateOrdered AND upg='post')    "# of post",
  SUM(c.date=pd.dateOrdered AND upg='exp')     "# of exp",
  SUM(c.date=pd.dateOrdered AND upg='upgrade') "# of upgrade"
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN phone_details pd
  ON c.date = pd.dateOrdered
  OR c.date = pd.dateReceived
GROUP BY c.date;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97e57d/1).

Comment: +1 Both for the join, and for adding the additional columns that the OP wanted but did not include in the query.

Comment: thanks very much this works great, I tried left join before i posted here and I think i got the date condition reversed thats why it didn't work the first time. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your join is correct as you should use an on and not a where :

```
from `phone_details` JOIN calendar
where calendar.date = phone_details.dateOrdered
```

Try using:

```
from `phone_details` JOIN calendar
on calendar.date = phone_details.dateOrdered
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select calendar.date,DAYNAME(calendar.date) as `day`,
sum(if((`phone_details`.`upg` = 'Post'),1,0)) AS `Post Paid`,
sum(if((`phone_details`.`upg` = 'Upgrade'),1,0)) AS `Upgrade`,
sum(if(((`phone_details`.`upg` = 'Exp') or (`phone_details`.`upg` = 'Future Exp')),1,0)) AS `Exp`,
(select count(id) FROM phone_details 
        WHERE dateReceived = calendar.date 
        )AS `received`

from `phone_details` JOIN calendar
ON calendar.date = phone_details.dateOrdered or calendar.date = phone_details.dateReceived

group by calendar.date DESC
```

This works fine.
You can check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b9ca/3